# For while loop condition

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
double velocity;
double time;
double acceleration;
char buff[10];
int y;

//Asking user for a time value
printf("Enter a time value in seconds: ");

//QC to make sure program is running correctly
fgets(buff, 10, stdin);
char x = buff[0];
y = isdigit(x);

if (y == 0)
{
   printf("Error. You have entered a non numerical number, please enter a numerical number\n");
}   
else
{
   sscanf(buff, " %lf", &time);

   //Displaying Velocity and Acceleration if time is between 0 and 120 seconds
   if (time >= 0 && time <= 120)
   {

      int k = time;
      for (k = 0; k <= 120 && k <= time; k = k + 5)
      {

         //Equation to find velocity and acceleration
         velocity = 0.000001 * pow(time, 3) - 0.00488 * pow(time, 2) + 0.75795 * time + 181.3566;
         acceleration = 3 - 0.000062 * pow(velocity, 2);

         printf("%.lf    %.1lf           %.3lf\n", time++, velocity++, acceleration++);
      } //for while loop
   } //if statement

   //Displaying an error message if time is inputted lower than 0 and greater than 120 seconds
   else
   {
      printf("Error. You have entered a value that is not between 0 and 120 seconds.\n");
   }
}

return 0;
```

Enter a time value in seconds: 10

```
10      188.4           0.798
11      189.1           0.783
12      189.8           0.768
```

Here is the result of the code. I am trying to print the result as follows: 0, 5, 10. Then the result of said seconds would print velocity and acceleration.

Any help would be appreciated. I am stuck
Thank you.

Comment: Not your issue, but do you really need this type of stuff `//for while loop` ? also are you sure you have the right language, because I'm not. please research the difference between C++ and C# and edit your tags accordingly

Comment: That isn't C# code.

Comment: `int k = time;` Then you promptly initialize the loop with `k = 0;`. Also, it should be a red flag that you don't actually use `k` inside the loop at all.

Comment: How well does that code compile with a C# compiler? That's C++ (well, it uses C's libraries, but it's C++)

Comment: I ran the code, it did not give me any error. When I inputted a time value ie 10 thats what it showed up.

Comment: @L33VI You got the language wrong. Whatever compiled your code was not a **C#** compiler.